# PHP - Inputting data into MySQL cell

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying put row['user'] into cell but it doesn't work.

When I uncomment "echo" it works fine.

**PHP:**

```
function mod_Something($database)
{
    $sql = "SELECT user FROM table_name";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($database, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $html = $html . '<tr><td>' . $row['user'] . '</td></tr>';
            // echo $row['user'];
        }
    return $html;
    }
}
```

I also have a **HTML** view file where I have:

```
<table id="data-table-basic" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>user</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         %mod_Something%
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I know that HTML isn't a function but I must return it because there is a script which allows to return "view".

Comment: What does it do? What do you expect it to do? Why?

Comment: it should put username from database into cell.

Comment: You might want to define $html before the while loop, otherwise the first time it tries to prepend it to the table row it doesn't exist.

Also, try changing the final return $html to echo $html

Comment: rather than `echo` do a `var_dump()` and let us know the output, also set error reporting on it will tell you whats up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: $html "function" is defined in other file

Comment: @PhpDude When I did var_dump every record shows but not in table

Comment: Well what is your var_dump response?

Comment: Names of users i did it like echo var_dump($html)

Comment: did my answer satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   function mod_Something($database)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT user FROM table_name";
        if ($result = mysqli_query($database, $sql)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr><td>' . $row['user']; . '</td></tr>';
            }
        return $html;
        }
    }


<table id="data-table-basic" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>user</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <?php mod_Something(); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting anything from the function **mod_Something** because you are not building & returning HTML properly.
See the below code.

```
function mod_Something($database)
{
    $html = "";
    $sql = "SELECT user FROM table_name";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($database, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $html .= '<tr><td>' . $row['user'] . '</td></tr>';            
        }    
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Hope this works for you!